# Two untagged VLANs on one port (ProCurve)

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, hp-procurve

Goodmorning

I'm setting up a new network.
My problem is that i have a management VLAN 99 and an IT VLAN 89.
Now i want to connect my laptop to one port and access both VLANs.

Because when i'm at my desk i want to be in my IT-vlan but also access my switches in webinterface and when port 11 is untagged 89 and tagged 99, i can't access it (security from a management VLAN).

Is there an access-list or something for your management VLAN, where you can set another VLAN or an IP-address, so you can access the management VLAN?

Hope that anyone can help me.

Kind Regards

Arne

Comment: Similiar to this - http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/access-multiple-vlans-from-one-computer

Comment: How is your port is configured. Trunk or hybrid.

Comment: How would you expect the switch to know what vlan the traffic is for? You are sending back untagged data it can't know what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two untagged VLANs on a single switch port, and wouldn't want to do that regardless.

You'll likely need two NICs in your machine, one on each VLAN, if you can't route between the VLANs. If your OS supports VLAN tagging and treating that as a separate interface, you could have one untagged and one tagged VLAN configured to do that on a single NIC.